# Provider type null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i Have a databasemanager class for accessing database and constants class which has database names and provider names. database and connectionstring works fine but provider name is null which raises an exception.
here is my code for databasemanager class

```
using System;
using System.Data;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ClsDataAccessLayer
/// </summary>
/// 

namespace MyAcademy.Forms
{
    public class ClsDatabaseManager
    {
        #region [Member Variables]
        private IDbConnection idbConnection;
        private IDataReader idataReader;
    private IDbCommand idbCommand;
    private Constants.DataProvider providerType;
    private IDbTransaction idbTransaction = null;
    private IDbDataParameter[] idbParameters = null;
    private string strConnection;
    private string _ServerName;
    private string _DatabaseName;
    private string _UserID;
    private string _Password;
    private string _IntegratedSecurity;
    #endregion
    #region [Constructors]
    public ClsDatabaseManager()
    {
        /*Default Constructor*/
        ServerName = string.Empty;
        DatabaseName = string.Empty;
        UserID = string.Empty;
        Password = string.Empty;
    }

    public ClsDatabaseManager(Constants.DataProvider providerType)
    {
        this.providerType = providerType;
    }

    public ClsDatabaseManager(Constants.DataProvider providerType, string
     connectionString)
    {
        this.providerType = providerType;
        this.strConnection = connectionString;
    }
    #endregion
    public string ServerName
    {
        get { return _ServerName; }
        set { _ServerName = value; }
    }
    public string DatabaseName
    {
        get { return _DatabaseName; }
        set { _DatabaseName = value; }
    }
    public string UserID
    {
        get { return _UserID; }
        set { _UserID = value; }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _Password; }
        set { _Password = value; }
    }
    public string IntegratedSecurity
    {
        get { return _IntegratedSecurity; }
        set { _IntegratedSecurity = value; }
    }
    private void SplitDatabaseConnectionString(string ConnectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] ConParams = this.ConnectionString.Split(';');
            foreach (string param in ConParams)
            {
                if (param.ToLower().Contains("database") || param.ToLower().Contains("initial catalog"))
                {
                    DatabaseName = param;
                    DatabaseName = DatabaseName.Substring(DatabaseName.IndexOf('=') + 1, DatabaseName.Length - (DatabaseName.IndexOf('=') + 1)).Trim();
                    continue;
                }
                if (param.ToLower().Contains("data source") || param.ToLower().Contains("server"))
                {
                    ServerName = param;
                    ServerName = ServerName.Substring(ServerName.IndexOf('=') + 1, ServerName.Length - (ServerName.IndexOf('=') + 1)).Trim();
                    continue;
                }
                if (param.ToLower().Contains("user") || param.ToLower().Contains("uid"))
                {
                    UserID = param;
                    UserID = UserID.Substring(UserID.IndexOf('=') + 1, UserID.Length - (UserID.IndexOf('=') + 1)).Trim();
                    continue;
                }
                if (param.ToLower().Contains("password") || param.ToLower().Contains("pwd"))
                {
                    Password = param;
                    Password = Password.Substring(Password.IndexOf('=') + 1, Password.Length - (Password.IndexOf('=') + 1)).Trim();
                    continue;
                }
                if (param.ToLower().Contains("integrated security"))
                {
                    IntegratedSecurity = param;
                    IntegratedSecurity = IntegratedSecurity.Substring(IntegratedSecurity.IndexOf('=') + 1, IntegratedSecurity.Length - (IntegratedSecurity.IndexOf('=') + 1)).Trim();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public static ClsDatabaseManager SplitDatabaseConnectionString(Constants.Databases eDatabase)
    {
        ClsDatabaseManager conString = new ClsDatabaseManager();
        try
        {
            string str = null;
            switch (eDatabase)
            {
                case Constants.Databases.Academy:
                    str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case Constants.Databases.UniversityDB:
                    str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniversityDBCon"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case Constants.Databases.HR_DB:
                    str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMCon"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case  Constants.Databases.Inventory:
                    str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Inventory"].ConnectionString;
                    break;

            }
            string[] arr1 = str.Split(';');
            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] arr2 = arr1[i].Split('=');
                switch (arr2[0])
                {
                    case "Data Source":
                        conString.ServerName = arr2[1];
                        break;
                    case "Initial Catalog":
                        conString.DatabaseName = arr2[1];
                        break;
                    case "User ID":
                        conString.UserID = arr2[1];
                        break;
                    case "Password":
                        conString.Password = arr2[1];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return conString;

    }

    public static ClsDatabaseManager InitializeDbManager(Constants.Databases eDatabase = Constants.Databases.Academy)
    {
        string ConnectString = String.Empty;
        switch (eDatabase)
        {
            case Constants.Databases.Academy:
                try
                {
                    ConnectString = Utility.Decrypt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ConnectString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
                }
                break;
            case Constants.Databases.Account_DB:
                try
                {
                    ConnectString = Utility.Decrypt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountDB"].ConnectionString);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ConnectString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountDB"].ConnectionString;
                }
                break;

            case Constants.Databases.HR_DB:
                try
                {
                    ConnectString = Utility.Decrypt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMCon"].ConnectionString);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ConnectString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMCon"].ConnectionString;
                }
                break;

            case Constants.Databases.UniversityDB:
                try
                {
                    ConnectString = Utility.Decrypt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniversityDBCon"].ConnectionString);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ConnectString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniversityDBCon"].ConnectionString;
                }
                break;
            case Constants.Databases.Inventory:
                try
                {
                    ConnectString = Utility.Decrypt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Inventory"].ConnectionString);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ConnectString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Inventory"].ConnectionString;
                }
                break;
        }
        string ProviderType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["System.Data.SqlClient"];
        Constants.DataProvider DP = (Constants.DataProvider)Enum.Parse(typeof(Constants.DataProvider), ProviderType);
        ClsDatabaseManager dbManager = new ClsDatabaseManager(DP, ConnectString);
        dbManager.SplitDatabaseConnectionString(ConnectString);
        return dbManager;
    }
    #region [Properties]
    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return idbConnection;
        }
    }

    public IDataReader DataReader
    {
        get
        {
            return idataReader;
        }
        set
        {
            idataReader = value;
        }
    }

    public Constants.DataProvider ProviderType
    {
        get
        {
            return providerType;
        }
        set
        {
            providerType = value;
        }
    }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return strConnection;
        }
        set
        {
            strConnection = value;
        }
    }

    public IDbCommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return idbCommand;
        }
    }

    public IDbTransaction Transaction
    {
        get
        {
            return idbTransaction;
        }
    }

    public IDbDataParameter[] Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            return idbParameters;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region [Public Functions]
    public void Open()
    {
        idbConnection =
        ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetConnection(this.providerType);
        idbConnection.ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString;
        if (idbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            idbConnection.Open();
        this.idbCommand = ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetCommand(this.ProviderType);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (idbConnection != null && idbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            idbConnection.Close();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        this.Close();
        this.idbCommand = null;
        this.idbTransaction = null;
        this.idbConnection = null;
    }

    public void CreateParameters(int paramsCount)
    {
        idbParameters = new IDbDataParameter[paramsCount];
        idbParameters = ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetParameters(this.ProviderType,
          paramsCount);
    }

    public void AddParameters(int index, string paramName, object objValue, ParameterDirection direction = ParameterDirection.Input)
    {
        if (index < idbParameters.Length)
        {
            idbParameters[index].ParameterName = paramName;
            idbParameters[index].Direction = direction;
            idbParameters[index].Value = objValue;
        }
    }
    public void AddParameters(int index, string paramName, object objValue, int size, ParameterDirection direction = ParameterDirection.Input)
    {
        if (index < idbParameters.Length)
        {
            idbParameters[index].ParameterName = paramName;
            idbParameters[index].Direction = direction;
            idbParameters[index].Value = objValue;
            idbParameters[index].Size = size;
        }
    }

    public void AddParameters(int index, string paramName, object objValue, DbType type, ParameterDirection direction = ParameterDirection.Input)
    {
        if (index < idbParameters.Length)
        {
            idbParameters[index].ParameterName = paramName;
            idbParameters[index].Direction = direction;
            idbParameters[index].Value = objValue;
            idbParameters[index].DbType = type;
        }
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        if (this.idbTransaction == null)
            idbTransaction = idbConnection.BeginTransaction();
        //idbTransaction =
        //ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetTransaction(this.ProviderType);
        this.idbCommand.Transaction = idbTransaction;
    }
    public void BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel level)
    {
        if (this.idbTransaction == null)
            idbTransaction = idbConnection.BeginTransaction(level);
        //idbTransaction =
        //ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetTransaction(this.ProviderType);
        this.idbCommand.Transaction = idbTransaction;
    }
    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        if (this.idbTransaction != null)
            this.idbTransaction.Commit();
        idbTransaction = null;
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        if (this.idbTransaction != null)
            this.idbTransaction.Rollback();
        idbTransaction = null;
    }

    public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        CloseReader();
        this.idbCommand = ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetCommand(this.ProviderType);
        idbCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
        PrepareCommand(idbCommand, this.Connection, this.Transaction, commandType, commandText, this.Parameters);
        this.DataReader = idbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        idbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        return this.DataReader;
    }

    public void CloseReader()
    {
        if (this.DataReader != null && !this.DataReader.IsClosed)
            this.DataReader.Close();
    }

    private void AttachParameters(IDbCommand command, IDbDataParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        foreach (IDbDataParameter idbParameter in commandParameters)
        {
            if ((idbParameter.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
            &&
              (idbParameter.Value == null))
            {
                idbParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            command.Parameters.Add(idbParameter);
        }
    }

    private void PrepareCommand(IDbCommand command, IDbConnection
      connection,
      IDbTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string
      commandText,
      IDbDataParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = commandText;
        command.CommandType = commandType;

        if (transaction != null)
        {
            command.Transaction = transaction;
        }

        if (commandParameters != null)
        {
            AttachParameters(command, commandParameters);
        }
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        CloseReader();
        this.idbCommand = ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetCommand(this.ProviderType);
        PrepareCommand(idbCommand, this.Connection, this.Transaction,
        commandType, commandText, this.Parameters);
        int returnValue = idbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        idbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        return returnValue;
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar(string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        CloseReader();
        this.idbCommand = ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetCommand(this.ProviderType);
        PrepareCommand(idbCommand, this.Connection, this.Transaction,
        commandType, commandText, this.Parameters);
        object returnValue = idbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        idbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        return returnValue;
    }

    public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        CloseReader();
        this.idbCommand = ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetCommand(this.ProviderType);
        PrepareCommand(idbCommand, this.Connection, this.Transaction, commandType,
          commandText, this.Parameters);
        IDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = ClsDatabaseManagerFactory.GetDataAdapter
          (this.ProviderType);
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = idbCommand;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        idbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        return dataSet;
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string commandText, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    {
        DataSet ds = ExecuteDataSet(commandText, commandType);
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            return ds.Tables[0];
        else
            return null;
    }

    #endregion
    internal void CreatePerameter(int p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

and below is the constansts code

```
using System;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Constants
/// </summary>
namespace Constants
{
public enum DataProvider
{
    Oracle = 1,
    SqlServer = 2,
    OleDb = 3,
    Odbc = 4
}
public enum Databases
{
    Academy = 1,
    UniversityDB = 2,
    Account_DB = 3,
    HR_DB=4,
    Inventory=5
}
```

}

Comment: Where did the debugger say the error was?

Comment: Line 222:            Constants.DataProvider DP = (Constants.DataProvider)Enum.Parse(typeof(Constants.DataProvider), ProviderType);

Comment: There is no "question" in your question.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this yourself? Perhaps the 'ProviderType' is wrong?

Comment: These are the 4 dataproviders which i use but couldn't connect it is always null

Comment: shreesha i have been working on it for 5 days everything is fine just the provider type is null

Comment: i guess the provider name is not passed from the constants class to the databasemanager.

Comment: yes it is a variable it is contained in the constants class

Comment: can you please study my code and give me a solution

Comment: i dont know the answer but surely the problem is `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["System.Data.SqlClient"]` which returns null to the string `ProviderType`

Comment: Here is the answer and possible duplicate question :[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings - Returns Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470541/configurationmanager-appsettings-returns-null).

Comment: off course the debugger stops here but don't know how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert the value to its string representation.

string ProviderType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["System.Data.SqlClient"].ToString();

Above line should be like this

```
string ProviderType = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"].ToString();
```

Comment: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings returns string.its because app.config is not in main project. actually ToString() method does nothing here.

Comment: off course first it needs a value to convert but the value is null so ToString(); won't help i need to get the value of ProviderType

Comment: In your App.config do you have a key System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: and there is no App.config file there

Comment: my fault. do you see web.config?and the key in that

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=ADEELYAZDAN;Initial Catalog=Academy;Integrated Security=True "/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: this is the connectionstring in web.config

Comment: Use ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["connection"].ToString();.You have to use the name not provider name

Comment: Worked now just had to put the provider name in the key in web.config

Comment: Thanks alot for your hint shreesha